# Can xsds describe choice with coincident element names?

Tags: xml, xsd

a very simple example would be

take this

```
<root>
  <car type="car" engine="1200"/>
  <plane type="plane" wings="2"/>
  <car type="car" engine="1200"/>
</root>
```

is described by xsd with a choice like this

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="car">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="engine" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="plane">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="wings" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

sadly my xml is like this (I didnt design it)

```
<root>
  <vehicle type="car" engine="1200"/>
  <vehicle type="plane" wings="2"/>
  <vehicle type="car" engine="1200"/>
</root>
```

which would imply an xsd like this

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="vehicle">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="engine" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="vehicle">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="wings" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

which gives me

```
Warning     Multiple definition of element 'vehicle' causes the content model to become ambiguous. A content model must be formed such that during validation of an element information item sequence, the particle contained directly, indirectly or implicitly therein with which to attempt to validate each item in the sequence in turn can be uniquely determined without examining the content or attributes of that item, and without any information about the items in the remainder of the sequence.
```

is there a way around this, but keeping the choice? e.g. can i constrain the the choices by more than just the element name? e.g. to include the type?

Comment: Type alternatives introduced in XSD 1.1 should allow this.

Comment: let me look that up